# How to download alpine linux packages over tor

Tags: alpine-linux, apk-tools

In Debian, one can install `apt-transport-tor`, which allows packages to be downloaded over tor (to prevent an observer from seeing what packages you are installing).  Is there an equivalent in Alpine Linux, or a way to configure apk to work through a SOCKS5 proxy?

Answer (score 1):

apk does not have built-in support for tor.
But still you can use tor and torsocks in order to accomplish the same result.
Alpine has both packages already available since version 3.5, so you can simply type:

```
apk add tor torsocks
```

Copy `torrc.sample` shipped in `/etc/tor` to `/etc/tor/torrc` and modify the config file according to your needs/setup.

A very simple config for `/etc/tor/torrc` is:

```
Log notice file /var/log/tor/notices.log
DataDirectory /var/lib/tor
ControlPort 9051
CookieAuthentication 0
```

Then, start tor with:

```
 rc-service tor start
```

Verify that your tor anonymizer is working with:

```
 torify curl ipinfo.io
```

The ip address shouldn't be your public ip address.

At this point, you can go ahead and use apk with torify:

```
 torify apk update
```

apk has support for proxy via env variable `HTTP_PROXY`.
At this point then you have several options.
You might want to consider also sshuttle [*] (this is shipped by Alpine as well), and route the traffic for alpinelinux repositories subnet only via sshuttle.

[*] https://github.com/sshuttle/sshuttle

Hope it helps.

.: Francesco